# Rolling a dice, with a dice :)

Tags: android, dice

I currently need some advice about a "simple" issue.
I'm building a game helper, where users may roll dices (6 faced dice, 20 faced dice, etc). Actually, I displaying only the number to the user.
But, to make that much better to use, i want to display THE dice on the screen (on an alert dialog with custom layout for example). 
My problem is here, and I don't really know how achieve that. I can't believe that the only way is to create each face of the dice to display it.

For your information, I need theses dices : 6 faced, 8 faced, 12, 20 and special 6 faced. :) That will be a very long task if I have to create all dices :(

The best i can dream, is to have the dice animation, but i guess is a bit too complex for me at this time.

Anyone as some advice about it ?

Comment: Note that "dice" is the plural of "die".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best Quality / Highest Effort:**

If you want to show a 3-D tumbling die, you probably want to look into the free 3D modeling/rendering/simulation packages. *Blender* is the first that comes to mind, although there are probably easier free alternatives. They take some time to learn, but you can model a photo-realistic 3D solid and then animate them in real physical simulations.

Going that route, you'd render short (GIF?) animations for each. Then you just have to look up how to display an animated GIF in a dialog (there's plenty of examples available).

**Lower Quality / Less Effort**

You could just display a single, 2D face of the die being rolled on your dialog, with a number (or pattern of dots) in the center. Depending upon the type of die, the 2D outline of the face could be a square, triangle, pentagon, etc.

The drawing logic for this would be fairly trivial (again, many examples available online). You could even do a crude animation, by having it cycle through several values before stopping on one. Have the cycling rapid at the start and slow at the end, and add a little 'click' sound for each, and you'd have something users would probably like.

Comment: Thank's for that answer. I guess i will go for the second option. But I think i will learn the first one, which should be nice :).

Comment: Don't forget to up-vote the folks who volunteered their time to help you. ;-)

Comment: sure, it's done :) btw i have not enough reputation to my upvote being displayed instantly, apparently